# setting object property from api call to cached data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

update: after using nanoid to generate unique ids, ive seen that on a browser refresh, the fetch will generate new ids for each team. so whatever team i may have saved earlier, after the reload, the app will fetch data again and a new nanoid is generate for that same team. any solutions to this? the only one i can think of it caching the data in another file for now and possibly set up firestore in the future.

I am building an nba stat tracker app and i am working on a feature for the user to be able to save a team, and on a window reload or when the user revisits the app, i want the browser to be able to check a favoriteTeams state array to check if a team is in the favorites list and update an object property when the data is being fetched. on a window reload, the favorite teams state still contains the favorite teams, but the isFavorite property is not being set if the favoriteTeams state includes the team that is being loaded into the updatedTeams array.

```
fetch (/** api data */)
.then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const updatedTeams = data.response.map((team: Team) => {
        return {
          ...team,
          isFavorite: favoriteTeams.includes(team) 
        };
      });
      setTeams(updatedTeams);
    })
    .catch(err => window.alert("Could not load data. Refresh and try again"));
  }, [season]);
```

Instead of checking if the whole team object is in the favTeams state i checked the id but that also isnt working

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use object equality to find the team in `favoriteTeams`. [That's never going to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/283366). What sort of data is in `favoriteTeams`? Seems you should just store an ID property or similar

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're trying to use object equality to find the team in `favoriteTeams`. [That's never going to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/283366).

Assuming you're using `localStorage`, store a simple JSON array of Season+ID properties instead.

Then use that to synchronise the `isFavorite` property.

```ts
// use a ref to prevent recalculating every render
const favoriteTeams = useRef<Set<string>>(
  new Set(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteTeams') ?? '[]')),
);
const [teams, setTeams] = useState<Team[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(/* api data */)
    .then((res) => (res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res)))
    .then(({ response }) => {
      setTeams(
        response.map((team) => ({
          ...team,
          isFavorite: favoriteTeams.current.has(`${season}_${team.id}`),
        })),
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.warn(err);
      alert('Could not load data. Refresh and try again');
    });
}, [season]);
```

You can use something like this to toggle team favourites though your usage may vary

```ts
const toggleFavorite = (team: Team) => {
  const isFavourite = team.isFavourite;
  const key = `${season}_${team.id}`;

  setTeams((prev) =>
    prev.toSpliced(prev.indexOf(team), 1, {
      ...team,
      isFavorite: !isFavorite,
    }),
  );

  if (isFavourite) {
    favoriteTeams.current.delete(key);
  } else {
    favoriteTeams.current.add(key);
  }
  localStorage.setItem(
    'favoriteTeams',
    JSON.stringify([...favoriteTeams.current]),
  );
};
```

Comment: Would love to know what's wrong with this. Please leave a comment so I can fix it

Comment: yeah i was using object equality. the json response does come with id's associated with each team, but to get the data for each season, i have to make another fetch and there are overlapping ids between different seasons and different teams. i tried to use these ids but because of the overlap, it didnt work. i was thinking of using nanoid to reassign unique ids for each team in their respective reason. ill need to do some refactoring and let you know what happens!

Comment: @asadimran___ in that case, try combining the ID and season to form a unique key

Comment: that a great idea lol ill do that